# convert to stamp time format from string c#

Tags: c#, parsing, date

I use javascript to pick a date and display the format as (11-05-2015 17:37)

and I try to parse it to date time as the code below

```
DateTime taskDate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate.Text);
```

and save it into my date base like

```
TO_DATE('" + createOn + "')
```

its give me and error call "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

anyone have any others method to parse it to stamptime ?

the txtDate.Text value is 27-05-2015 09:37.

Comment: Take a look at DateTime.ParseExact : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DateTime.ParseExact or DateTime.TryParseExact

Check below code:

```
DateTime taskDate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtDate.Text, "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Or

```
DateTime taskDate;

if (DateTime.TryParseExact(txtDate.Text, "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out taskDate))
{
    //code if date valid
}
else
{
    //code if date invalid
}
```

Comment: Rohit, its work, but the thing is i need to parse the txtDate.text to stamptime in order to save into database..

Comment: While storing it to database convert datetime to sqlFormattedDate like below:
string sqlFormattedDate = taskDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

Answer (score 2):

`Convert.ToDateTime` uses your current thread culture format when converting from string to datetime.

If string you converting from has another format, you need to use `DateTime.ParseExact` and explicitly provide appropriate format.

For example, in you case it should be

```
DateTime taskDate = DateTime.ParseExact("11-05-2015 17:37", "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Also have a look to [custom datetime format strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for your reference.

Comment: Andy I do appreciate your comment, but this method I has been applied before and it still throw me the same error.

Comment: @LstPatrick In fact, code snippet I've posted doesn't throws any exception. Probably, you're trying to convert sting in another format, not exactly in one you've shown.